# PHP "Cannot unset string offsets" mink behat Selenium2Driver.php

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

Started Selenium:

```
java -jar vendor\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar
```

Ran: `php run.php Test.xlsx`

Getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in....src\Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver.php on line 101`

Inside run.php I have:

```
$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver(
'firefox', 'base_url'
```

If I remove, base_url, I do not get an error and the tests run headless, no browser.

This works fine on another machine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The second param. is array of Capabilities for Selenium Driver (pass null if any) and the third param. is the base_url

```
$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver(
'firefox', null,  'base_url');
```